# ubuntu mate 18.04 | window border themes do not work

Tags: 18.04, compiz, themes, mate

i'm using the compiz window manager and i have tried to change themes which change the window borders, but they do not appear to work.
how can i fix that?

Here is a picture which shows that i enabled a specific theme which should give me a different window border from what i'm getting:

As you can see the icons are different from what they should be in the small picture of the window border:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Where have you downloaded the problematic themes? Do you have any problems with pre-installed themes? Please also add output of `env | egrep "COMPIZ|DESKTOP"` to the question.

Comment: i downloaded them from gnome-look. the problem only appears with themes which should change the window borders to look like mac os